# mqtt mosca pahojs WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1884/mqtt' failed/timeout

Tags: node.js, mqtt, paho

### Broker

```
var mosca = require('mosca')


var settings = {
  port: 1884
};

//here we start mosca
var server = new mosca.Server(settings);
server.on('ready', setup);

// fired when the mqtt server is ready
function setup() {
  console.log('Mosca server is up and running')
}

// fired whena  client is connected
server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
  console.log('client connected', client.id);
});

// fired when a message is received
server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
  if (packet.cmd === 'publish') {
    //Qui uso mongo DB 
    console.log('Published: ', packet.payload.toString('utf8'));
  }
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic
server.on('subscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('subscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic
server.on('unsubscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('unsubscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client is disconnecting
server.on('clientDisconnecting', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnecting : ', client.id);
});

// fired when a client is disconnected
server.on('clientDisconnected', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnected : ', client.id);
});
```

### client.html

```
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./mqttws3.1.js"></script>
      <script>
  var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client( 'localhost', 1884, 'clientId');

  client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
  client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
  client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});

  function onConnect() {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  console.log("onConnect");
  client.subscribe("/World");
  message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
  message.destinationName = "/World";
  client.send(message); 
};
function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
  if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0)
  console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
};
function onMessageArrived(message) {
  console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
  client.disconnect(); 
};  
      </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

I run the broker

```
node broker
```

than I call the client.html by a web server
like

```
http://localhost/client.html
```

I get after a while

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at
>   ws://localhost:1884/mqtt. this.socket = new WebSocket(wsurl,
>   ["mqtt"]);
>
> Chrome : WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1884/mqtt' failed:
>   WebSocket opening handshake timed out

I don't know which way to turn :(

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at this:

https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/wiki/MQTT-over-Websockets

It looks like you have just started a normal MQTT listener not a WS listener.

You need to add a http block to the settings:

```
var settings = {
  http: {
    port: 1884,
    bundle: true,
    static: './'
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the point I didn't see it. But now I've got a strange issue if I run with your setting I've got events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1146:14)
    at listen (net.js:1172:10)
    at net.js:1270:9
    at dns.js:85:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

Comment: Did you take the port:1884 out? That error implies something is already using port 1884

Comment: I've tried like https://gist.github.com/whisher/e61bfde612ba16e11986 with node v0.12.2